# How can I make my nested for output align on right in C++?

Tags: c++

I was just learning about nested for and one of my tasks is to make my output align on right, but I can't quite figure out how I can do that

**My code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x,y;

    for (y=1; y<=5; y++)
    {
        for (x=y; x<=5; x++)
        {
            cout<<"*";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    getch();
}
```

**The Output:**
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wEP1.png)

**What I want to make:**
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgBgm.png)

Comment: You have to add spaces before your output. So, for the first line, you add zero spaces, for the second line, one space, and so on.

Comment: Your expected output has spaces in front of the stars. Your program never outputs any spaces...

Comment: I thought about that too, but I still can't figure out the code for it, can you help me show how it's done?

Comment: You know how to output a certain number of stars for each line. What's the issue with now also outputting a certain number of spaces for each line?

Comment: To be fair, it's a code from my task book, I just rewrite the code to visual studio code, and one of the tasks is to make the output align on the right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure you want to use a C function but this works. A possible way to accomplish this task is to add padding in front of the character you want to print.  with printf, using '*' in the format string will tell printf to get the value from the arguments. So,

```
printf("%*s", y, " ");
```

s will be filled by the char " " and the padding will be filled by y, you loop counter.

```
#include <cstdio>


int main()
{
    int x,y;

    for (y=1; y<=5; y++)
    {
        for (x=y; x<=5; x++)
        {
            printf("%s", "*");
        }
        printf("\n");
        printf("%*s", y , " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine. Make sure you print space first and then *. As we row number increase the space increases by 1 and * decreases by 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int rows=5,i,j,space;
    for (i = rows; i >= 1; --i) {
      for (space = 0; space < rows - i; ++space)
         printf("  ");
      for (j = i; j <= 2 * i - 1; ++j)
         printf("* ");
      printf("\n");
}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, please allow me to make you aware of this discussion on whether/how much providing full code solutions (explained or not) is actually considered to be a good answer for a homework question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0):

In accordance with [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)
I offer a hint:
Always print the full line length and make sure that you either print enough `" "` beforehand,
or use the special formatting features of your chosen output method to do the indenting/aligning automatically.

For explicitly printing `" "` you can either decide for each character, whether you print `" "` or `"*"`,
or you can print enough `" "` in a first inner loop and do the printing of `"*"` in the second inner loop as in the code you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

To align on the right, you need to print some blank characters before the stars.
This is easily performed with the help of the `std::string` constructor

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//#include <conio.h>
//using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 5;
    for (int y = 1; y <= n; y++)
    {
        std::cout << std::string(y-1, ' ') << std::string(n-y+1, '*') << std::endl;
    }
    //getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To align on the right on a line of 5 width , you can use `std::right` (in iostream) and `std::setw` (in iomanip) like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
    
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    int x,y;
    
    for (y=1; y<=5; y++)
    {
        stringstream buf1;
        for (x=y; x<=5; x++)
        {
            buf1 << "*";
        }
        cout << right << setw(5) << buf1.str() << endl;
    }
}
```